# Measure android activity running time(staying activity on screen)

Tags: android, android-activity, sdk

now I develop android application, and I need activity running time!
from `onCreate()` to `onPause()` or `onStop()`.

I know to do that use `System.currentTimeMillis`!

But I want just API or SDK function to do that.

May be when task be go to change onPause() or onStop(), android have information of activity running time!(or forward activity).

so I use one code or function, I will measure to activity running time!(staying activity on the screen!)

so what API or function have measure activity running time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google analytics or any third party analytic(eg: Flurry, InMobi etc) tool for getting the activity running time. Using this, you can track the user's activity state and mostly using-feature inside the application.

For Google Analytics integration refer the following link.

http://developer.android.com/distribute/analyze/start.html

For Integrating the flurry analytics, please refer the following link.

https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/android/

Google Analytics and Flurry Analytics provide event tracking feature to track the Activity running time and usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this below code calculate total foreground time by calculating diff between pause and resume time.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    long pauseTime = 0, resumeTime = 0;

    SharedPreferences preference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        preference = getSharedPreferences("TimeWrap", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        pauseTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preference.edit();

        long totalForgroundTime = preference.getLong("TotalForegroundTime", 0) + (pauseTime-resumeTime);

        editor.putLong("TotalForegroundTime", totalForgroundTime);

        editor.commit();

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(
                                                     String.valueOf(TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(totalForgroundTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) + " Seconds");

}

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

         //update foreground time
        resumeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


    }

}
```